# Dropbox doesn't use indicator icons

Tags: 16.04, dropbox

Ubuntu 16.04;
Dropbox Version: 2015.10.28.
In the past Dropbox was successfully using indicator icons from `/home/yuranos/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-35.4.20/images/hicolor/16x16/status`

However, it's not the case now. The images are fetched from some other place obviously, they are always plain grey, and I was able to get only 2 of them:
[image]

And when updating:
[image]

The icons from the Dropbox image folder are completely different:
[image]

Comment: I think it depends on your theme mine acts normal if I use the default Ubuntu theme but abnormal when I use another theme.

Comment: Maybe, but it worked fine with this theme in the past. It's definitely some regression.